# Unable to touch UISlider

Tags: ios, objective-c, uislider

I have a view hierarchy like:

```
View >
  > UIImageView
  > UISlider
  > BottomView
    > UIScrollView
       > View1, View2, View3...
    > FootView
```

[image]

As you can see the black view = self.view, Messi is the UIImageView beneath that is the bottom view in blue outline that contains the scroll view with multiple sub views. The slider is in between them. Footview holds the cross button.

When the view is initially loaded the UISlider works fine. As soon as I hit a different View2/View3 etc the Slider stops responding. What could be the issue here?

Comment: Did you use any gesture recognizer anywhere in the view?

Comment: No I didn't use any recognizers

Comment: Gosh! I wasted many hours only to find that the slider max and min value was set the same accidentally.